# disable submit button after one click with spring dojo

Tags: spring, dojo

i hav a form by which i submit data and using below code for validation. the validation is working fine  . what i need is after clicking on submit i want to disable the button

```
Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ValidateAllDecoration(
    {
        elementId : 'submit',
        event:'onclick'

    }));
<button type="submit" name="_eventId_submitmaterial" id="submit">Add Material</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this in your onClick handler ?

```
this.set("disabled", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Dojo has a function called `_setDisabledAttr()` that takes a `boolean` value.  When I have a submit button, I use

```
buttonToDisable._setDisabledAttr(true);
```

in my `onClick` function.  If I'm making an AJAX call then, when the call returns, I use

```
buttonToDisable._setDisabledAttr(false);
```

in my success and error functions to re-enable the button.